# Data Binding works in code-behind, but not in XAML Possibly ItemsControl Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have several bindings in my code, but I'm not sure why only this one fails in xaml.

```
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <wpfExp:SignalGraph
                  x:Name="signal_graph"
                  Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                  <!--PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"-->
                  Signal="{Binding}" 
                  signal_graph_window_width="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=signal_graph_window_width, Mode=OneWay}"
                  X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
                  MaxTimeValue="{Binding Source = {StaticResource ResourceKey=signal_data}, Path = MaxTimeValue, Mode=OneWay}"
              />
```

only the commented line fails. Meanwhile, if I go into code behind:

```
private void SignalGraph_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      loaded = true;

      Binding b1 = new Binding();
      b1.ElementName = "signal_box";
      b1.Path = new PropertyPath("GraphPenWidth");
      b1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
      b1.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
      this.SetBinding(PenWidthProperty, b1);

      Width = signal_graph_window_width;
      SignalBox sb = VisualTreeUtilities.FindVisualParent<SignalBox>(this);
      DrawSignals();
```

}

this works. To me they both seem the same.

But the only possible explanation that I can think of is that maybe when I write the binding in xaml, the Binding takes place at a different time rather than on load event like the code behind.  If it is too early, before signalgraph is actually created, then maybe it doesn't bind correctly? but i'm not getting a binding error message.  Quite confused.

Comment: Is `GraphPenWidth` a dependancy property? If it isn't then it may be being set sometime after the bindings are instantiated and it won't be firing a propertychanged event.
Also, `UpdateSourceTrigger` has no effect on a one way binding.

Comment: does the `Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_box ...` or `signal_graph_window_width="{Binding ElementName=signal_box ...` binding works?

Comment: Yes, graphpenwidth is a dependancy property. Also, the other bindings all work. Even the graphpenwidth binding works when i put it in code behind.

Ah ok, will remove updatesourcetrigger. I was just going crazy and trying everything. I can't see why it works in code behind but not in xaml like the rest of my bindings.

I swear it somehow relates to being an itemtemplate or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was going on. Basically I accidentally had set a value to the DependencyProperty using the .net property setter and it was overwriting the binding. When I did the bind in code behind, I put the binding in the loaded event block, but in xaml, the binding was occurring in the constructor for the higher level control, so it would get overwritten later.

thanks for all the ideas and help thinking about it